# not able to find controller in FOSRestful using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

i am trying the `FOSRestful` example in `Symfony 2` version but i am getting following error

> Cannot import resource "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/UsersController"
>   from
>   "/Library/WebServer/Documents/symfony/app/config/routing_dev.yml".
>   Make sure the "AcmeDemoBundle" bundle is correctly registered and
>   loaded in the application kernel class.

as i am new to it so i dont know whether FOSRestfulBundle is being installed properly or not so here i am posting all the steps

till now i have done following things to set up

1 . in `AppKernel.php`

> ```
>  new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
>  new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
> ```

2 . in composer.json

> ```
> "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
> "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "dev-master"
> ```

3 . in config.yml

> ```
> fos_rest:
>     routing_loader:
>         default_format: json
> ```

4 . in routing_dev.yml

> ```
> users:
>     type:     rest
>     resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/UsersController"    
>     prefix: /users
> ```

5 . following is the content of `UsersController`  , which is inside 
     `Acme/DemoBundle/Controller`

```
<?php



namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Model\User;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Model\UserQuery;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class UsersController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function allAction()
    {
        $users = UserQuery::create()->find();

        return array('users' => $users);
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function getAction($id)
    {
        $user = UserQuery::create()->findPk($id);

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found');
        }

        return array('user' => $user);
    }
}


?>
```

6 .composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "dev-master"


    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: could you show your composer.json file? It could be that the namespace for Acme isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it by appending `.php` extension to `UsersController` in `routing_dev.yml`

so that correct entry is

```
resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/UsersController.php"
```